# PyQT5 error: could not find or load Qt platform plugin xcb

Tags: qt, python-3.x, anaconda, pyqt5

Up until `Anaconda3` (which contains `Python 3.4`) was re-installed on my `RedHat 6.5` workstation, I have been able to develop Python apps that use `PyQT5`.

Post re-install of `Anaconda` I receive an error message:

> ....could not find or load Qt platform plugin xcb

The only difference between Anaconda installs is the folder name: `/usr/local/ananaconda3` vs `/usr/local/anaconda_py3`

I checked `libqxcb.so` has no missing dependencies.
I rebuilt `PyQT5`.
I tried explicitly adding location of `site-packages` of `PyQT5`:

```
import site
site.addsitedir("...path.../python3.4")
```

Any other suggestions?

How does re-installing `Python` impact the use of `PyQT5`?

Comment: Try to reinstall Libxcb as in : http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Linux.2FX11

Comment: I should mention I have [tag:PyQt4] installed in [tag:Anaconda].   Perhaps there is a problem having both together?

Answer (score 7):

This is an error caused by having two different versions of Qt under the same installation/environment.

Check the packages installed and their versions in your environment (if for some reason you're not working in a virtual environment, you can skip the first line):

```
source activate yourenvname 
conda list
```

If you see `pyqt` and `qt` both with version `4.X.X` then remove them (assuming you want to work in Qt v5):

```
conda remove qt
conda remove pyqt
```

Comment: I have multiple versions of Qt on my system. But when I write `conda remove qt` it asks me to remove `Qt 5.6.0` which is the version I'm using and don't want to remove. Since I'm using Debian Jessie I have the Qt 4.8 (or so) preinstalled and probably this is the version that Anaconda is using. Is there a way to select which Qt version to remove? Is it actually removing the actual Qt installation or is it just removing the Anaconda packages?

Comment: Can't you do `conda remove qt 4.8`?

Comment: I have the same problem. I set environment variable QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/anaconda_py3/pkgs/qt-5.6.0-0/plugins and it worked.
I uninstalled it and reinstalled anaconda again. It also solved even without this environment variable. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue that seems to match what happened here.
But in my case the solution was to "sudo rm -rf user/anaconda3" and reinstall it with "bash anaconda....sh", because I had previously installed it using sudo ("sudo bash anaconda....sh")