# python app - xcb plugin fail

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, xcb

My setting: Python 2.7 with anaconda

Recently I have installed OpenCV 3.0 and when I try to do simple image display or I want to run python samples that come with OpenCV, there is a error message:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

I have read many comments that I need to attach .so files to my project but I don't think it's the optimal solution since for most people it works out of a box.

I have no clue what to do. I'm inexperienced. What comes to my mind is only to reinstall everything.

Comment: Oh, I just read that if I want to use Qt5 I should NOT use cmake flag  -D WITH_QT=ON. reference: http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/ can someon approve and explain why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Qt5 works fine with OpenCV 3.1.0. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430845/pyqt5-error-could-not-find-or-load-qt-platform-plugin-xcb) is what worked for me for resolving the "xcb" error.

Apparently the Anaconda `qt` and `pyqt` [packages](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) (v4) were shadowing the system v5 version.

If you want to work with Qt5 try removing these via:

```
conda remove qt
conda remove pyqt
```

(Ubuntu 16.04, OpenCV 3.1.0, Anaconda 4.1.1, Qt 5)

Answer (score 2):

Okey, I have figured it out.

During cmake I set flag `-D WITH_QT=OFF` since I read somewhere that it doesnt work for Qt5.x