# OpenCV error on spyder

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

I want to use OpenCV with python on spyder.

But error occured when I run a simple code.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('pi.png',0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
dcv2.destroyAllwindows()
```

**Error**

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

The error is occured at this line.

```
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

**Details: Ubuntu 14.04(LTS), OpenCV 2.4.13, Spyder 2.3.9(Python 2.7)**

Please Tell me in detail what should I do.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483753/python-app-xcb-plugin-fail

Comment: I've already checked that page, but I didn't understand answer.

Comment: However the problem is solved from referring to this page's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand the answer.( [stackoverflow.com/questions/30483753/python-app-xcb-plugin-fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483753/python-app-xcb-plugin-fail) )

But, the problem is solved from changing condition when I reinstall OpenCV

Installation is referred to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV).

The key of the solution in this method is simple!

Change the condition from '**WITH_QT=ON**' to '**WITH_QT=OFF**' in the script.  (*opencv.sh*)

I don't have any solution without reinstalling because I'm inexperienced.

If you know about solution that change the condition without reintalling or reason why the problem is occured, give me a feedback please.

Thank you.