# PyQt5 could not load the platform plugin xcb

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Running the following Qt example on a fresh new dedicated `virtualenv` session:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
hello = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello World!", None)
hello.show()
app.exec_()
```

triggers the following error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

I read some posts related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051790/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430845/pyqt5-error-could-not-find-or-load-qt-platform-plugin-xcb) but they apply to conda and do not resolve my problem. Would you have any idea ?

EDIT: running the script with debug support triggers the following output:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/pellegrini/venvs/inspigtor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

Comment: What is the output of `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python your_script.py` ? or add `import os os.environ["QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"] = "1"` before `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just edited my post with the debug output. A library is missing but this should not happen through a virtualenv install. No ?

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install -y libxcb-xinerama0` and run the script

Comment: solved by installing `libxcb-xinerama0` manually. Strange but at least it works. Thanks